Equivalent to inspect.isFunction and inspect.ismethod that work with cython?
I currently have python 3 code that looks like this:
if inspect.isfunction(type) or inspect.ismethod(type):
   # do stuff

unfortunately we ended up getting inconsistent behavior with this logic depending on rather someone was running or linux or windows.  The reason turned out to be that the library method, imported elsewhere in the code, turns out to be a cython method in linux which inspect doesn't consider to be a method so my if statement is never entered.
Is there an equivalent to the above call that will treat python and cython methods as methods (dido for functions) without my having to add an additional checks for cython functions and methods to my if statement?
callable() is not an option since there are non function/method callables that this logic shouldn't run on.
